# Adding strings and newlines to value of readonly type="text" input tag

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I've been trying to figure out how to get new lines appended to the value of an input tag.

```
...
<div id="heroDisplay">
    <form>
        Super Powers:<br> <input id="superpowers" type="text" readonly />
    </form>
</div>
...
var superpowersDiv = document.getElementById("superpowers")
for (var i=0; i<heroObj.superpowers.length; i++)
{
    superpowersDiv.value += heroObj.superpowers[i]
    superpowersDiv.value += "<br/>"
    //I've also tried adding "\n" and "\r"
}

Output: X-Ray Vison<br/>Flying<br/>...
               OR
Output: X-Ray Vison\nFlying\n...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Input elements do not have any content. Perhaps you need a textarea element, they don't have any markup content but you can create new lines with "\n".

Comment: @RobG I'll try that and get right back to you, thanks!

Comment: @RobG Thank you very much that seems to have done the trick! I do still wish the other way were possible though...